# Display images with .pdf extension into a list view in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a list view which displays the list of employee details. The details includes an image of an employee along with their details.

The details are displayed correctly but only jpg/jpeg/png images are displayed but pdf is not. I cant restrict the user not to upload pdf image.
Why the image is not displayed? Do i require a pdf reader?
What is to be done to display an pdf type image in the list view.
Please help!!!

Comment: PDF isn't an image - it's a PDF :) Browsers doesn't support it as image. You have to convert the PDF images to supportable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `IFrame` to show your PDF ,

This is CodeProject reference of how to [Display the Pdf content in div](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/699129/Display-the-Pdf-content-in-div) !

You can modify and try to add IFrame to your ListView .